# Is it possible to run a private Hex (Erlang) dependency manager (and if so how)?

Tags: erlang, rebar3, hex-pm

I'm working in an Erlang environment. I'm looking to establish a dependency manager so that our build server can publish binaries for reuse instead of using source code dependencies. The [Hexpm GitHub project](https://github.com/hexpm) implies that it is possible to run it outside of the hex.pm website, but I don't see any instructions for doing so. Specifically, I would like my build server to be able to publish packages either directly (via the filesystem) or via rebar3, and for subsequent rebar3 builds to be able to use those published packages

1. Is it possible to run Hex on my own server?
2. If so, where would I find some documentation on how to set it up (or provide the instructions directly)?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at https://github.com/hexpm/hex_web there are instructions in the README.md for both installing and running it. It's a phoenix application, so it should all be relatively familiar ground if you've looked at the phoenix framework before.

As for getting rebar3 to work with your installation, there is documentation here as to the config values to use for setting the URLs to use for hex packages: http://www.rebar3.org/docs/hex-package-management.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for those pointers. I was looking at https://github.com/hexpm/specifications and it says that to host a repo the repository endpoint has to be implemented. Does following the instructions on running hex_web also deploy the repository endpoint?

Comment: Yes, it is a full implementation. In the README.md for the hex_web repo (linked in orig comment), it even notes how to seed some sample data into the repository.